# cython: run prange sequentially (profiling/debugging)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, parallel-processing, cython

I have a meanwhile pretty large code base written mostly in Cython. Meanwhile, I've started parallelizing it by replacing "range"s by "prange"s. (So far more or less at random, as I still have to develop a gut feeling as to where I really profit from this and where not so much.)

One big question to which I haven't found an answer arose when profiling/debugging:

**Is there a way to turn off parallelization (i.e. run "prange"s sequentially) at either a global or local level?**

A global switch would be most convenient, but even if there's a local solution that should at least allow me to implement a global switch myself.

Just in case it's relevant: I'm using Python 3 (currently 3.4.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least three very easy ways:

1. `prange` takes a `num_threads` argument. Set that equal to 1. This gives you local control.
2. If you compile without OpenMP it'll still still run, but not in parallel. Remove `extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp']` and `extra_link_args=['-fopenmp']` (or equivalent) from setup.py. (OpenMP is implemented in terms of `#pragmas` so just gets ignored without compiler support). This gives you an easy global switch.
3. OpenMP [defines an environmental variable for the maximum number of threads](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/528373) `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. Set that to 1 in your operating system and then run your cython program. This gives a global switch (without recompiling)